# Sum of probabilities of multiple drawings

Tags: probability

Assume that we have three boxes:
Box1 contains a red ball and a blue ball
Box2 contains a green ball and a yellow ball
Box3 contains a black ball, a white ball and a gray ball

The probability of choosing Box1 is 0.5, Box2 is 0.3 and box3 is 0.2.

If we draw five Balls randomly with replacement. Considering the drawings with the highest probabilities, how many ways can have sum of probabilities higher than a specific threshold, e.g. >90%?

Comment: What do you mean by "Considering the drawings with highest probability"? There is one event with the highest probability which is drawing the red ball all five times.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I mean the highest probability is having te read ball 5 times, another drawing will be the second most probable event and so on, the third, forth...

Comment: If you are considering events in a specific order of decreasing probabilities, then what do you mean by the number of ways sum of probabilities can be greater than a threshold. The sequence is fixed (upto permutations in equally likely events) so there is only one way this sequence can cross a given threshold.

Comment: I mean if you have the highest probability e.g. 0.5, the second highest probability e.g. 0.3 the third highest probability e.g. 0.1 and the following probabilities are smaller than 0.1. In this case, there is 3 ways that the sum of their probabilities is equal to 0.9

Comment: Does the order of drawing matter or is a draw identified by number of balls of each color? Is the real question "what is the minimum number of different draws so that the sum of their probabilities is higher than 90%"?

Comment: Thanks Ymh, yes the order matter and the right question is "what is the minimum number of different draws so that the sum of their probabilities is higher than 90%"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table below draws are grouped into Types by how many balls from each box they have and are ordered by descending probability.

CP - Color Permutations, e.g. Type 20 has draws with $2^13^4$ different ball color orders from each box.

DP - Draw Probability, e.g. each draw in Type 2 occurs with $p=\frac{0.5^40.3^1}{32}$

OC - Order Combinations, e.g. in Type 3 there are $\binom{5}{2}$ combinations of box orders, affecting the total number of draws that fall in this Type

T - Total number of draws of this Type, CP times OC

S - Sum of probabilities

```
Type | Box 1 | Box 2 | Box 3 | CP  | DP       | OC | T    | S
-----+-------+-------+-------+-----+----------+----+------+--------
   1 |     5 |     0 |     0 |  32 | 0.000977 |  1 |   32 | 0.03125
   2 |     4 |     1 |     0 |  32 | 0.000586 |  5 |  160 | 0.09375
   3 |     3 |     2 |     0 |  32 | 0.000352 | 10 |  320 | 0.2375
   4 |     4 |     0 |     1 |  48 | 0.000260 |  5 |  240 | 0.3
   5 |     2 |     3 |     0 |  32 | 0.000211 | 10 |  320 | 0.3675
   6 |     3 |     1 |     1 |  48 | 0.000156 | 20 |  960 | 0.5175
   7 |     1 |     4 |     0 |  32 | 0.000127 |  5 |  160 | 0.53775
   8 |     2 |     2 |     1 |  48 | 0.000094 | 30 | 1440 | 0.67275
   9 |     0 |     5 |     0 |  32 | 0.000076 |  1 |   32 | 0.67518
  10 |     3 |     0 |     2 |  72 | 0.000069 | 10 |  720 | 0.72518
  11 |     1 |     3 |     1 |  48 | 0.000056 | 20 |  960 | 0.77918
  12 |     2 |     1 |     2 |  72 | 0.000042 | 30 | 2160 | 0.86918
  13 |     0 |     4 |     1 |  48 | 0.000034 |  5 |  240 | 0.87728
  14 |     1 |     2 |     2 |  72 | 0.000025 | 30 | 2160 | 0.93128
  15 |     2 |     0 |     3 | 108 | 0.000019 | 10 | 1080 | 0.95128
  16 |     0 |     3 |     2 |  72 | 0.000015 | 10 |  720 | 0.96208
  17 |     1 |     1 |     3 | 108 | 0.000011 | 20 | 2160 | 0.98608
  18 |     0 |     2 |     3 | 108 | 0.000007 | 10 | 1080 | 0.99328
  19 |     1 |     0 |     4 | 162 | 0.000005 |  5 |  810 | 0.99728
  20 |     0 |     1 |     4 | 162 | 0.000003 |  5 |  810 | 0.99968
  21 |     0 |     0 |     5 | 243 | 0.000001 |  1 |  243 | 1
```

The answer is: to exceed 90%, out of 16807 possible, we need 8653 most likely draws. All 7744 draws of Types 1 through 13 and any $\lceil\frac{0.9-0.87728}{0.000025}\rceil=909$ draws of Type 14, which feature 1 ball from Box 1 and 2 each from the others.